# How to send informations from a fragment to another hosting different TabbedActivites

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have a TabbedActivity (OngletCours) with 3 tabs. Each tab has a listView and when I click on it, an AlertDialog opens. One of the options is to go to another TabbedActivity(OngletJalonNotes) that has 2 tabs.

I use database in my app. I want to be able to create some 'Jalon'depending on the item I clicked on in the first TtabbedActivity (the item's id I clicked in the TabbedActivity will be the FK of a table of my db).And I want to display them in a ListView

I'm doing like this : on the fragments of the first TabbedActiviy, I used a Bundle and FragmentManager to send the ID of the item, and in the fragment 'Jalon' I tried to get the value I passed, but I got a NullPointerException. How can I fix this ? I really need to get the  ID in the second fragment so that Ii can use it in the method.

Here's the firstFragment 'CoursActuel' code of the positive Button of the AlertDialog :

```
     .setPositiveButton("Ajouter des jalons à ce cours", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            int idcours = cursor_modifier.getInt(0);
                            OngletJalonsAfficher onglet = new OngletJalonsAfficher();
                            Bundle args = new Bundle();
                            args.putInt("idcoursfk",idcours);
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            onglet.setArguments(args);
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,onglet,"");
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        }
                    });
```

And in the fragment 'OngletJalonsAfficher' :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_onglet_jalon_afficher, container, false);

    //NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION HERE
    int idcours = getArguments().getInt("idcoursfk");

    final ListView lvJalonsPasse;
    lvJalonsPasse =(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListJalonsPasse);


    final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    final DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    Cursor cursor = dbhelper.getAllJalonsPasse(//i need to put the value 'idcours' here...);
    String[] from = { "date_jalon", "designation_jalon" };
    int[] to = { R.id.text_branche_cours, R.id.text_designation };
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.list_row, cursor, from, to, 0);
    lvJalonsPasse.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return rootView;
}
```

Thank you for the future help guys ! Tell me if you need more code !

Answer (score 0):

You've created a bundle but never attached it to a fragment. 
 
Something like this

```
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

BTW:   `int idcours = getArguments().getInt("idcoursfk");` is a potential NPE,  better do like:

```
 Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
           idcours = bundle.getInt("idcoursfk");
        }
```

`int idcours = cursor_modifier.getInt(0);` Same here, NPE

Comment: Oh i forgot that... but why I'm still not going to the other fragment when I click ? Did I miss something in the first fragment ?

Comment: as an example FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

fragment.setArguments(bundle);          
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.you_fragment_container, fragment, "");
fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: you wrote 'R.id.you_fragment_container', that is the id i put on my ViewPager in the xml file of the TabbedActivity right ?

Comment: If i run on debug mode, at the end of my first code, i go to the second fragment and Ii get the value i puted in the bundle, but it doesn't show my new fragment..